# Is there a way to create an array of objects using the Key value pairs of an object as values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object

```
const myObject = {rice : 10, wheat: 20, sugar: 3}
```

I would like to convert it to an array of object:

```
myArray = [
{"product" : rice, "QTY" : 10},
{"product" : wheat, "QTY" : 20},
{"product" : sugar, "QTY" : 3}
]
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) can serve:

```js
const myObject = {rice : 10, wheat: 20, sugar: 3}

const result = Object.entries(myObject).map(([product, qty]) => ({ product, qty }));  
console.log(result);
```